# somafm radio rhythmbox 13.04 not working problem

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

No Somafm internet radio channels work for me in rhythmbox, in 13.04 (using the default install, no extra plugins or upgrades).

It adds the playlist, resolving the media URL, but when I play nothing happens. Other internet radio works fine.

Example [playlist](http://somafm.com/spacestation.pls) and [URL](http://mp2.somafm.com:2666).

Answer (score 1):

Are your firewall rules blocking high ports? Try http://somafm.com/fw/spacestation.pls which forces a port 80 server.